# Conveniently view vector's content if iterator given

Tags: vector, stl, iterator, visual-studio-debugging

Is there convinient way to see vector's content if i need to debug a program in Visual Studio 2013 which uses function signatures like this:

```
void foo(Iterator beginA, Iterator endA);
```

in case i have `vector<int> a` i can easily see what is inside of the vector. But if i given only iterator, then, for debug purpose, i need to declare vector just to see what is inside, or there exists easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like `beginA._Ptr,10` in the Watch window. This relies on an implementation detail of the iterator (that it has a member called _Ptr), and the `,10` syntax in the Watch window means "treat the pointer as an array address and show me 10 elements of the array". You can put an arbitrary number there, doesn't have to be 10, of course.

HTH